# How to send POST request with search term obtained from autocomplete in Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am using an auto complete form (Django-ajax-selects) which returns a dropdown list of items from the database. After a user clicks on an item, the search field is populated with the name of the item. I want to be able to take whatever term is in the search bar, and then after the user presses enter, the page navigates to the post the user entered into the search bar.

```
<form method="POST" action="/builds/show/">{% csrf_token %}
```

The url above in `action` needs to have the name of the item in the database appended to it.
So if the name of the item in the database is `First Post`, the url in `action` should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="/builds/show/First__Build">{% csrf_token %}
```

What I want to know if there is any way to take the term from the input field, which looks like this in html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." name="search" id="id_postField" onkeyup="searchOpen()" data-plugin-options="{&quot;min_length&quot;: 1, &quot;html&quot;: true, &quot;source&quot;: &quot;/builds/autocomplete/ajax_lookup/PostsTable&quot;}" data-ajax-select="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" value="" name="postField"></input>
```

I know how to do it in Django using named urls, but is there any way to get this done on the html side?

This is an example of how the ajax auto-complete looks like:
[image: Example]

Comment: Is the jquery autocomplete?

Comment: yes I am using ajax autocomplete which uses jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to set the action attribute on the form like this:

```
$("#id_of_form").attr("action", "/builds/show/" + $("#id_postField").val())
```

Where `#id_of_form` is your form id or any other selector you may use to select your form.

Comment: thanks, I tried that, and it almost works, but it redirects me to:
`http://127.0.0.1:8003/builds/show/undefined/`. It is filling it in as undefined. 
I have: `$("f").attr("action", "/builds/show/" + $("id_postField").val() + "/")`

Comment: you could add an if statement and check if $("id_postField").val() != undefined first before setting the action attribute.

Comment: Does $("id_postField").val() always return undefined or just when you have not selected a value yet?

Comment: if your autocomplete plugin is not automatically setting the selected value in the input field you may have to manually set the value after the select event has occurred.

Comment: using firefox to inspect the HTML, even before I type in anything, the action="" is already set to the undefined url.